# C++ MFC SDI Copy/Paste did not work

Tags: c++, mfc, sdi

I have created a simple MFC SDI Application with an Ribbon. The View for the Document is a FormView with on Edit Control.

If I now use CTRL+V to paste some Text in the Edit Control nothing happens. Same goes with CTRL+C to copy the Text inside the Edit Control.
I could use the Context Menu if i right click inside the Edit Control.
But how can i enable the Shortcuts?
The CTRL + C etc is inside the Accelerator List.
If i add the following to the MainForm

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame, CFrameWndEx)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_EDIT_COPY, &CMainFrame::onCopy)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

and the Function itself

```
void CMainFrame::onCopy() {
    AfxMessageBox(L"Copy");
}
```

If i now press CTRL+C the MessageBox Pops up. But i could not copy the text of the Edit Control to the Clipboard.
How could I chose between copy text from an Edit Text and doing something else if a different control is selected and CTRL+C is pressed(e.g. if i select text inside the Edit Control it should be copied to the clipboard. If i select e.g. an Item from a Tree View only a popup should shown)?

Comment: When you would use google, you would find an answer. Took less than 10 seconds https://bytecrunchers.wordpress.com/2012/05/31/copy-text-from-clipboard-in-mfc-2/

Comment: Believe it or not i did the google thing to find a solution and also hit that post but this did not helped me. What if i had more then one edit control how to determine the one who is currently selected? How to get the Text of that Textbox to the Clipboard?

Comment: Get the active control and get the text from it.

Comment: Maybe post a `WM_COPY` message to the active control? Otherwise removing Ctrl+C from the accelerator would also work (your accelerator will not be capturing the message, but the edit-box does process it, so if this is enough to you...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` to enable/disable command. Use `ON_COMMAND` to respond to the same command.

You then have to forward the message to the edit control (`m_edit.Copy()`). You can do this directly in `CMyView` class (remove the handler from `CMainFrame`)

If there are more than one edit control, `GetFocus` will report which edit control has focus.

`CEdit::GetSel` will report if selection is available.

Do the same with paste. Use `m_edit.CanPaste()` to see if paste is available. Use `m_edit.Paste()` for paste command.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame, CFrameWndEx)
    //ON_COMMAND(ID_EDIT_COPY, &CMainFrame::onCopy)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyView, CView)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_EDIT_COPY, &CMyView::OnEditCopy)
    ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_EDIT_COPY, &CMyView::OnUpdateEditCopy)
    ...
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

class CMyView : public CView
{
    CEdit m_edit1, m_edit2;
    ...
};

void CMyView::OnEditCopy()
{
    CWnd *wnd = GetFocus();
    if(wnd == &m_edit1)
        m_edit1.Copy();
    else if(wnd == &m_edit2)
        m_edit2.Copy();
}

void CMyView::OnUpdateEditCopy(CCmdUI *pCmdUI)
{
    CWnd *wnd = GetFocus();
    int start, end;
    if(wnd == &m_edit1)
    {
        m_edit1.GetSel(start, end);
        pCmdUI->Enable(end > start);
    }
    else if(wnd == &m_edit2)
    {
        m_edit2.GetSel(start, end);
        pCmdUI->Enable(end > start);
    }
}
```

Or you can do this in `CMainFrame`, you have to find the handle to the view class and edit control.

Also make sure accelerator key is added.